# is there a way for Chrome RDP to be accessed by 100 users simultaneously AS VIEWER ONLY (so that they can't click anything)?

Tags: google-chrome, remote-access, remote-server, remote-desktop

I want to demonstrate my working LIVE to my customers, and I don't want them to disturb me while seeing at my process. (AND NO STREAMING, because i need to do this non stop, and don't have unlimited traffic)

is there a way for Chrome RDP to be accessed by 100 users simultaneously AS VIEWER ONLY (so that they can't click anything)?

or maybe another apps also (not only in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but it is OK for Windows Server too)

Comment: Then why not stream on twitch / youtube?

Comment: streaming will consume traffic a lot... i need to stream everyday non stop